# functions and infinite intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $f$ be a function.
If it is given that $$ f\left[\bigcap_{a\in A}F_{a}\right]\subseteq\bigcap_{a\in A}f[F_{a}]$$

then, if it is further given that $f$ is one to one, prove that the $\subseteq$ can be replaced with an =.

I am fairly certain that my proof is wrong, as I am useless at proofs. :( 
Here is what I have :

let $$x \in \bigcap_{a \in A}f[F_{a}]$$

then
$$ x \in f[F_{a_{1}}] \text{  and} x\in f[F_{a_{2}}] ...$$
$$ \text {  so  }f(x) \in F_{a_{1}} \text{  and} x \in F_{a_{2}} $$
$$ f(x) \in \bigcap_{a \in A} F_{a} $$
$$ x \in f\left[\bigcap_{a \in A} F_{a}\right] $$

please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

First a minor technical objection: the index set $A$ need not be countable, so you can’t assume that you can list it as $a_1,a_2,\dots\,$.

Your major error comes when you go from $x\in f[F_a]$ to $f(x)\in F_a$: $x\in f[F_a]$ means that there is some $y\in F_a$ such that $x=f(y)$. However, since you’re assuming that $f$ is one-to-one, this $y$ is unique and is simply $f^{-1}(x)$. Thus, from $x\in F_a$ you can infer that $f^{-1}(x)\in F_a$. You can do this for each $a\in A$, so you can now conclude that $f^{-1}(x)$ belongs to every one of the sets $F_a$ with $a\in A$ and hence that

$$f^{-1}(x)\in\bigcap_{a\in A}F_a\;.$$

Now apply $f$ to both sides to conclude that

$$x=f\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)\in f\left[\bigcap_{a\in A}F_a\right]\;,$$

which is exactly what you wanted.